transforming view from activity to a DialogFragment
can someone tell me how can i achive a transform animation from a CardView in my MainActivity , into another CardView inside a DialogFragment i want to popUp , heres the code that opens the DialogFragment :
fun openDialogFragment( df: DialogFragment = AlarmEditorFragment() ) {
   // what i want to do here , is to transform the binding.newAlarmButton to df.binding.alarmTimeContainer , both are CardView .
   df.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, GetSettingOptions(this).accentColor)
   df.show(supportFragmentManager, tag)
}

i could'nt find the way to acheive this all over the internrt

or i havent searched enough XD

